# Hibernate IllegalArgumentException while persisting entity object: Cannot set field 'id' to entity object?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I try to persist an entity object but I get a nasty IllegalArgumentException. Looking at the stacktrace doesnt give me much info. Somehow hibernate tries to set the id field of the entity object to the actual entity.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Long com.hosting.hostinginterface.spring.user.User.id] by reflection for persistent property [com.hosting.hostinginterface.spring.user.User#id] : com.hosting.hostinginterface.spring.user.User@246a5eb6
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha3.jar:6.0.0.Alpha3]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5411) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha3.jar:6.0.0.Alpha3]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5036) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha3.jar:6.0.0.Alpha3]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:292) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha3.jar:6.0.0.Alpha3]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:529) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha3.jar:6.0.0.Alpha3]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha3.jar:6.0.0.Alpha3]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha3.jar:6.0.0.Alpha3]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha3.jar:6.0.0.Alpha3]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:680) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha3.jar:6.0.0.Alpha3]
    ... 76 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field com.hosting.hostinginterface.spring.user.User.id to com.hosting.hostinginterface.spring.user.User
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-6.0.0.Alpha3.jar:6.0.0.Alpha3]
    ... 84 common frames omitted
```

Here is my entity class:

```
@Entity
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
  private String userName;

  @Column(name = "firstName", nullable = false)
  private String firstName;

  @Column(name = "lastName", nullable = false)
  private String lastName;

  private LocalDate birthday;

  @Column(name = "birthdate", nullable = false)
  private String birthdayText;

  public User() {
  }

  @Contract(pure = true)
  public User(String userName, String firstName, String lastName, @NotNull LocalDate birthday) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.birthday = birthday;
    birthdayText = birthday.toString();
  }

  public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
  }

  public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
  }

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }

  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  public LocalDate getBirthday() {
    return birthday;
  }

  public void setBirthday(LocalDate birthday) {
    this.birthday = birthday;
  }

  public String getBirthdayText() {
    return birthdayText;
  }

  public void setBirthdayText(String birthdayText) {
    this.birthdayText = birthdayText;
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

Changing the generation method of the id does'nt seem to solve the error so I'm out of potential answers...

Comment: Your getter and your setter for ID should both use the type `Long`.

Comment: I changed my setter to Long but still get the same error.

Comment: Hibernate Version ?

Comment: My version is 6.0.0 Alpha3

Comment: it is bug in version hibernate version higher 4.1.9 (Not sure). Change your hibernate version to 4.1.9

Answer (score 0):

Try this for `id` field

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
```

Do you have `birthday` column in database table? I suggest it should have `@Transient` to not be saved to database

Another thing you can try is to exclude `spring-boot-devtools`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about birthday :) Unfortunately the exception still gets thrown after changing the generation type

Comment: Another thing you can try is to exclude `spring-boot-devtools`. I have edited the answer

Comment: I have done the same, unfortunately without success.